# Как получить значение переменной из скрипта?

Tags: python

К примеру у меня есть скрипт на `python` который выполняет роль конфигурационного файла. То бишь в нем объявлены некоторые переменные, для инициализации некоторых из них вызываются функции. Так вот: как можно получить значение одной из переменных не редактируя сам конфиг?

Comment: как понять "не вмешиваясь"?

Comment: @eri в смысле не редактируя сам конфиг

Comment: а где получить переменную нужно?

Comment: Чтение файла входит в понятие "редактирование"? Если читать можно, то просто найти переменную через регулярные выражения.

Comment: @eri в поток вывода

Comment: @AlioshcaZ с каких пор редактирование входит в чтение? Регулярные выражения - абсолютно не вариант - я же писал что некоторые переменные инициализируется через функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим структура файлов такая

```
app/
    config.py
    app.py
```

тогда в app.py переменную можно  получить

```
from config import peremennaya
print(peremennaya)
```

В поток вывода

```
python -c "from config import peremennaya; print(peremennaya)"
```